# Callback Function - Auth0 and Passport.js

Tags: node.js, passport.js, auth0, restify

I have the code below that acts as a callback for Passport.js and Auth0. My problem is that when I try to output `req.user`, the result is `undefined`.

```
var passport = require('passport');
var restify = require('restify');

var callback = passport.authenticate('auth0', function(req,res,next){
   console.log(req.user);
   res.send('test');
});

module.exports = {
   get: callback
}
```

Comment: you did everything else right? like using the `passport-auth0` strategy and defined the serialize deserialize user?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty Yes. Everything was working already when the calls were in my server.js file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I eventually made was to put the callback function in the main JS file and not in a separate route.